# what if pglogical provider node gets stopped?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, pglogical

I have implemented the master-master bidirectional replication using **Postgres pglogical extension** on Ubuntu. Trying different scenarios that if one of the nodes gets down / shut down, will the process run normally.

**Scenario one:** I shut down the subscription node, and added some new records at the provider node. Started the subscription node again and checked it is missing some records if compared to the provider node. what should be the process here to sync all data as soon as the node gets started?

**Scenario two:** I shut down the provider node, and added some records at the subscription node. Started the provider node again and checked the subscription status was down, I dropped the subscription and created it again but was not able to replicate it.

Is it essential for all nodes to be in a running state, or is there a risk of data loss if some nodes are not operational?